# Lamport's rule for \multicolumn not valid?

Tags: multicolumn

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r|r@{\,}l|}
1&2&300\\
10&-2&X\\
\multicolumn{2}{r@{\,}}{2}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{X}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

According to Lamport, the columns formatting consists of three parts:

`r|` + `r@{\,}` + `l|`

hence I would expect the two X's to be in the same position. But the X in the third line is shifted to the right (compared to the X in the second line).

By trial and error I found a solution by replacing `\multicolumn{1}{l}{X}` with `\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{X}`. What is the reason behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only gave part of the rule, and the output you show is affected by the other part.

It is true that (apart from the first column) inter-column material from `@{..}` or `|` is added to the right hand edge of a column, so the `@{\,}` adds a thin space to the right edge of column 2, not the left edge of column 3.

But `@` (unlike the `!` added by the `array` package) does not only add the material specified in its argument; it *removes* the `\tabcolsep` space. `\tabcolsep` padding is added to *both* sides of each column and using `@` removes it from the right side of the current column *and* the left edge of the following.

So column 3 has no `\tabcolsep` padding on the left and is flush against column 2, the simplest way to achieve that in a `\multicolumn` is as you show, to apply `@{}` which adds nothing but removes `\tabcolsep` space.

Comment: Thank you! If I interpret your answer correctly, the @{\,} in \begin{tabular}{r|r@{\,}l|} replaces the entire intercolumn space between columns 2 and 3, whereas @{\,} in \multicolumn{2}{r@{\,}}{2}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{X} replaces only the first half of the intercolumn space between columns 2 and 3; but not the second half (preceeding column 3).

Comment: @LászlóBattha yes a multicolumn can not affect columns that it does not span.basically the final `@{...}` in a multicolumn argument acts like a final `@{...]` in a tabular argument and acts as if there is nothing to follow.